Git warning : Unable to access '*.iml' : Invalid Argument
I am running git status command and it is giving me following warning message so wondering if anyone can provide some explaination why it is giving this warning.
Note : I dont have any intellij *.iml file locally in that repo and neither in remote.
warning: unable to access '*.iml': Invalid argument
warning: unable to access '*.iml': Invalid argument
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean



Do you have *.iml or similar in your .gitignore or .gitattributes? Did you check the subdirectories for IML files?

Which version are you using?

@dan1st I checked subdirectories and i dont see *.iml files. Interesting thing is for any git based project if I run git status command it gives me that warning and yes I do have gitignore file which has reference to it that do not version control *.iml file.

@Marit i am using "git version 2.47.0.windows.1"

Try entering git config --list. This should show you the configuration git uses. Does that include anything similar to *.iml?

@dan1st yes it does have  "core.excludesfile=*.iml" in config

So after i removed that global config to exclude *.iml file I no longer getting warning messages

Clearing cache might help git rm --cached '*.iml' or try updating index so strays are removed git update-index --refresh
